# Extracting optional values from a string

Tags: regex, perl, sed

So, let's say I have the strings:

```
aaa -Dprop=var Class arg
aaa Class arg
```

I want a single one-liner (perl, sed, awk, doesn't matter) that can extract `arg` and `var` (if its there). Specifically, I'd like to return

```
arg var
arg
```

The following works for the first one:

```
echo "aaa -Dprop=var Class arg" | perl -pe 's|.*(-Dprop=([a-z]*)).*Class (.*)|\3 \2|'
```

but because `-Dprop=` is required, it obviously doesn't work the second one.

If, however, I make that match optional:

```
echo "aaa -Dprop=var Class arg" | perl -pe 's|.*(-Dprop=([a-z]*))?.*?Class (.*)|\3 \2|'
```

it doesn't work for the first one because, I believe the two .*s are greedy qualifiers and match -Dprop first.

If I make them non-greedy, it still doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

```
echo "aaa -Dprop=var Class arg" | perl -pe 's|.*?(-Dprop=([a-z]*))?.*?Class (.*)|\3 \2|'
```

So, first, what regex can I use that matches correctly? (I know I could split it into multiple commands, but I rather just have one).

Comment: +1 wow, someone that has actually tried to write some code before posting! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: "-Dprop=" is fixed or could be anything "foo=yourVar"?

Comment: @Kent, -Dprop is fixed, var can be anything (but in a specific format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
echo "aaa -Dprop=var Class arg"|perl -pe 's|(.*-Dprop=(.*))?.*Class\s*(.*)|$3 $2|'
```

Notice too that \3 is better written as $3 (which the warnings pragma would divulge).

Comment: +1 overall, but a bit more tweaking is probably needed: if `$2` is present, it will include any whitespace before `Class`.

Comment: All I needed was the concept. That line obviously wasn't the exact line I'm parsing. I never thought about including the first wildcard in the optional match.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's|^.*?(?:-Dprop=([\S]+))?\s+Class\s+(.*?)$|\2 \1|'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "aaa -Dprop=var Class arg\naaa Class arg"|
sed 's/.*-Dprop=\([^ ]*\).*\( \)Class \([^ ]*\)\|.*Class \([^ ]*\)/\3\2\1\4/'
arg var
arg
```